# Помогите с пагинацией

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

Есть сайт `https://www.houzz.ru/ideabooks` с очень странной пагинацией.
Страницы указаны как везде.... но по факту ссылки на страницы следующего формата
Cтраница 1-`https://www.houzz.ru/ideabooks`;
Cтраница 2-`https://www.houzz.ru/ideabooks/p/11`;
Cтраница 3- `https://www.houzz.ru/ideabooks/p/22`;
и т.д
Помогите. Что необходимо прописать в range()?
Заранее благодарю.

Есть код

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
import time
import json


url = "https://www.houzz.ru/ideabooks/"

headers = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
# print(soup)

data = []
for p in range(???):
    print(p)

    url = f"https://www.houzz.ru/ideabooks/p/{p}"

    r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
    sleep(5)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

    all_name_links = soup.find_all(class_="gallery-text__title hz-track-me")

    for item in all_name_links:
        item_text = item.text
        item_href = item.get("href")

        data.append([item_text, item_href])

with open("all_name_links.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(data, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй использовать в range все 3 аргумента, ведь у range есть (начало, конец-1, ШАГ). Задайте шаг для страницы равным 10. Но так же учитывайте и отклонение на 1 в финальной странице.
Надеюсь поможет.